# Carousel background images not loading with jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use jquery's .load function to insert a navigation bar + carousel into multiple html pages - my problem is that the background photos don't seem to be showing up.

This is part of the "header.html" file I am trying to load in with jQuery's .load:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img1.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img2.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img2.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

Below is the script I use to load in the carousel:

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").load("header.html", function() {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000 //changes the speed
        })
    });
});
```

css (linked in all pages that I am including the navbar/carousel):

```
header.carousel {
    height: 50%;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Where's your CSS? Those divs won't show if they have no content and there isn't a `height` specified in your CSS.

Comment: just added! the background photo css works fine when I don't use jQuery load, but I would not want to have to include the same navbar/carousel code in all my pages.

Comment: you're including `navbar.html` not `header.html`

Comment: sorry, the file was named navbar.html. It includes the navigation bar code as well as the carousel code. I've renamed it to header.html to avoid confusion. The code is successfully being loaded into my other pages, because the navigation bar appears, however the problem is still with the background images

Comment: try using absolute paths to the images.

Comment: Where is your #header that your jQuery is selecting? If it doesn't exist, your load ajax will not run, per the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: <div id="header"></div> is at the top of every html page I am including the header.html